# Characters not applying avatars correctly

Tags: unity, animation, models, controllers, rigging

[image]

I am trying to get different models to go through animation cycles in Unity. The first four models are from Mixamo. Does anyone know why my characters end up like this (lodged into the ground) when I press play? Each model is set as humanoid animation. I set the avatar definition for each to be created from their own model, and they have their own avatars and animator controllers. When I play, the model in the middle animates fine (idle animation) but the other two do not go into the idle state I am trying to send them into.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a misconfiguration on the animations.

Honestly, you should check out this post made on Unity Forums:
[How To: Getting Mixamo and Unity to work](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-getting-mixamo-and-unity-to-work.560284/), it's one of the most complete guides I've seen.

You've said that the models are set to Humanoid, but what about the animations?

In the post that I just mentioned, the following is said:

> 7. ...Okay, so click on the animation that you just imported into your project folder. In the inspector window, click on Rig, now change that from Generic to Humanoid and click apply. If you followed the steps correctly, no red or yellow errors here.

Oh, and another thing, you didn't mention if you're using the same Idle animation for each character, so I'm assuming you're not. Still, even if it's not the case, there may be a misconfiguration somewhere else.

I doubt that the problem is something else, since it's usually not the case, so try the above first.